# Connecting Squirrel Client to Embedded Teiid Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, squirrel-sql, teiid

I have a Spring Boot project, on which I have some csv files and have converted them into entities and querying them based on my requirement. For this approach, I am using Teiid Spring Boot Starter, which is starting a embedded server -

This is the console startup log -

`````
Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:teiid:spring;PassthroughAuthentication=true;useCallingThread=true;autoFailover=true;waitForLoad=5000;autoCommitTxn=OFF;disableLocalTxn=true', username='null' ````
`````

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.teiid</groupId>
                <artifactId>teiid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.teiid</groupId>
                <artifactId>teiid-12.1.1-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>12.2.1</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/teiid-12.2.1-jdbc.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
    spring.application.name=Teiid-spring-boot

    spring.teiid.model.package=com.example.demo.model
    spring.teiid.file.parent-directory=src/main/resources/csv

    #######
    logging.level.org.teiid.spring=TRACE


    spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I have Squirrel SQL client setup, have added the driver for Teiid as well.
teiid-12.2.1-jdbc.jar

Squirrel SQL connection settings used -

```
name - Teiid
example url - jdbc:teiid:spring
website url - http://teiid.org
```

But while connecting, getting this following error -

```
teiid: JDBC Driver class not found
class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues that need to be fixed.

1. You do not need the `teiid-12.1.1-jdbc` dependency in pom.xml
2. Add `teiid.jdbc-enable=true` to your `application.properties` that will open a jdbc port `31000` for the application you built.
3. Run your application
4. Then add the Teiid JDBC driver to SquirreL (which you seemed to be already done)
5. Use the URL as `jdbc:teiid:spring@mm://localhost:31000` where `localhost` is host where you are running your teiid-spring application.

Comment: Tried the above approach, also added the logging level for teiid-jdbc. 
teiid.jdbc-enable=true
logging.level.org.teiid.jdbc=DEBUG. But now I'm getting this error message from Squirrel Client - `Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an SQL connection.
class java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Comment: is there any username/password for this type of connection? @RameshReddy

Comment: Got it. Changed localhost to my IP and also I had to provide ApplicationName=JDBC. Thank you all

Comment: ApplicationName=JDBC is not required, no user/password by default as it is embedded engine you built, of course you can add security layer if you want. If you want a full-blown server model also take look at WildFly based Teiid, where there is no need for Java code, it is all configuration and DDL for your VDB.

Comment: Is there any way we can change the bean name 'datasource' created automatically by Teiid. I have an application which already has a 'datasource' bean.

Comment: using the 'datasource' as the name for the bean is the only way to tie it back into the whole spring-data framework, so no. When Teiid is being used it is a primary assumption that all communications to other sources is happening through Teiid API not directly to the data source. If you have a choice to reconfigure existing data source, define its configuration with `spring.datasource.xxx.url` where xxx is the new name.Like here https://github.com/teiid/teiid-spring-boot/blob/master/samples/rdbms/src/main/java/org/teiid/spring/example/DataSources.java

Comment: After adding two beans now Teiid server is trying to connect to my MariaDB database, whereas it should pick its own datasource configuration. Please help Ramesh Reddy. ```Caused by: org.teiid.deployers.VirtualDatabaseException: TEIID40095 TEIID31070 Empty model;There are no tables, procedures or functions defined in this model bdsDatasource```

Comment: The error is saying that, there were no tables or procedures found in your added database to integrate with name `bdsDatasource`, there needs at least a single table. If you think there are tables, then sometimes setting the "schema" name for datasource helps. add `spring.datasource.bdsDatasource.importer.schemaName=foo" to your application.properties. See all the import proeprties to customize here http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/JDBC_Translators.html

Comment: Didn't work! I don't want Teiid to connect to my bdsDatasource. I want Teiid datasource to be separate from my bdsDatasource. Is there any way of doing this?